# MERN Stack - Error Received while deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mern

I have developed a MERN stack application and created the React build. The build works before deployment at the address

```
http://localhost:3304/
```

However when I try to deploy it I get the error below

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.17.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.17.0...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 79 packages in 1.784s
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_b4cd03b2
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run ../build
       
       + npm@7.15.1
       added 254 packages from 921 contributors and audited 333 packages in 8.161s
       
       13 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
sh: 1: run: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run ../build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.AcJvb/_logs/2021-06-02T08_22_03_806Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

The package.json file has the below lines added. The build which is the client code and the backend which is the server code are placed in two directories along side.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run ../build"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick question are you trying to deploy both backend and front end together with heroku?

In the past I've deployed my backend with heroku and my frontend with netlify

Comment: Yes. I am trying to deploy frontend and backend on heroku. I made the changes in package.json file of the backend folder. I created the ReactJS build. The I used the port mentioned in the backend in the browser and the site works. But when I try to deploy on heroku I receive the error mentioned.

Comment: I'm not the best with heroku but I would change my heroku-postbuild. I could be wrong but, it should look something like this `"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm  install && npm run build"`

whats the purpose of this section `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false ...`